# Android MediaPlayer onPrepared Method sometimes not called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a musicPlayer app and thus a SongPlayer class which implements the android MediaPlayer. The MediaPlayer runs as a Service.

Everything works fine!! The app plays all day long normally. But once in 24h approximately there comes a random song and the onPrepared method is never called.

The logic flow is as follows:

1) i create the mediaplayer (if not yet created)
2) i set the datasource 
3) i prepare the mediaplayer as async
4) in the onPrepared method i call the START method

Since the onprepared method is not called the START method is not called and the music player nevers starts palying the next song.

I made some analysis and it has nothing to do with a particular song, it happens on radon songs on random time.

No error is ever reported.

Any ideas where the problem might be????

Any idea on how to check if the onPrepared method is NOT CALLED? As a backup plan?

A summarization of the Code.

The code is much complexer since other methods are implemented (onComplete, onError, etc.) but these i have not included since they are not needed.

```
if(MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer == null){
          MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();}

MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer.reset();

MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer.setDataSource("http://"+SongPlayer.modS+SongPlayer.path);

MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer.prepareAsync();

MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                Log.e("OLE", "playThisSong onPREPARED");

               MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer = mp;
               MyGlobalAudioPlayer.mediaplayer.start();
            }
});
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Found the source of the problem. It was not with the MediaPlayer class. It was some other process in my app.

I have a service which every 60s makes an update to the server. In this method i also check if the player is really playing. If not i start something else.

It happend in a while that this update occured the same moment the MediaPalyer wanted to prepare the song. And the method was faster, thus the onPrepared was never called.

Comment: Are you calling setOnPreparedListener(..) before calling prepareAsync()?

Comment: Hi Nagesh. Actually no. The order of my isntructions is 1) setDataSource ; 2) prepareAsync; 3)setOnPrepareListener...  do you think this should be changed to 1-3-2 ??? I will try it but i do not understand why it works 99% of time through 3 days and 1% the onprepared is not called...

Comment: tried to put onprepared before calling prepareasync and it did not help

Comment: Problem solved. Look edited post.

Comment: You should still set the listener before calling prepareAsync; for the tiny chance that the thread that is created within prepareAsync completes faster than the current thread reaches setOnPreparedListener.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set an error listener?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)

Comment: Yes i have an ErrorListener but it never gets called ... 

the onPreparedListener does not get called
the onErrorListener does not get called

Comment: Did you see the comment above about making sure you call setOnPreparedListener _before_ calling prepareAsync?